# Is there any effect on the operations with the variables independent of consume atomic-load?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, stdatomic

As known, there are 6 [std::memory_order's](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), and 2 of its:

- acquire-semantic used for loads - avoids reordering Load-Load and Load-Store
- release-semantic used for stores - avoids reordering Store-Store and Load-Store

[image]

I.e. for acquire-semantic, only `S = local1;` can be executed after `X.load(std::memory_order_acquire);`:

```
static std::atomic<int> X;
static int L, S;
...

void thread_func() 
{
    int local1 = L;  // load(L)-load(X) - !!! can be reordered with X !!!
    S = local1;      // store(S)-load(X) - !!! can be reordered with X !!!

    int x_local = X.load(std::memory_order_acquire);  // load(X)

    int local2 = L;  // load(X)-load(L) - can't be reordered with X
    S = local2;      // load(X)-store(S) - can't be reordered with X
}
```

But which of reorders across `load(X)` can be for consume-semantic?

```
static std::atomic<int *> X;
static int L1, L2, S1, S2;
static int L, S;
...

void thread_func() 
{
    int *x_ptr_local = new int(1);


    int local1 = L1;  // load(L1)-load(X) - !!! can be reordered with X !!!
    S1 = local1;      // store(S1)-load(X) - !!! can be reordered with X !!!

    int dependent_x1 = *x_ptr_local;  // load(x_ptr)-load(X) - !!! can be reordered with X !!!
    S = dependent_x1;                 // store(S)-load(X) - !!! can be reordered with X !!!

    x_ptr_local = X.load(std::memory_order_consume);  // load(X)

    int dependent_x2 = *x_ptr_local;  // load(X)-load(x_ptr) - can't be reordered with X
    S = dependent_x2;                 // load(X)-store(S) - can't be reordered with X

    int local2 = L2;  // load(X)-load(L2) - !!! can be reordered with X !!!
    S2 = local2;      // load(X)-store(S2) - !!! can be reordered with X !!!
}
```

Is it true, that only operations with `dependent_x2` can't be reordered across `X.load(std::memory_order_consume)`?

And all of operations with variables `L1`, `L2`, `S1`, `S2` and `dependent_x1` can be reordered across `X.load(std::memory_order_consume)` - i.e. can be performed either before or after `X.load(std::memory_order_consume)`, isn't it?

Comment: Why couldn't `int local1 = L;` be reordered below `x_local` in the first example?

Comment: @2501  **(1)** `int local1 = L;` can't be reordered below **(2)** `int x_local = X.load(std::memory_order_acquire);`, because are both - Loads, and `std::memory_order_acquire` prevent Load-Load reordering - as shown on picture, isn't it?

Comment: I only see **2** to have acquire semantics, so just as `S = local1;` can go below **2**, so can **1**. What is so special about **1**?

Comment: @2501 Thank you! I fixed it, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677061/can-non-atomic-load-be-reordered-after-atomic-acquire-load

Comment: @Alex, Shouldn't `X` in your 2nd example be `std::atomic<int*>` instead of `std::atomic<int>*`?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes. Thank you! I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memory_order_consume` is used to preserve the ordering of data dependencies on the atomic object itself without using heavier synchronization such as that introduced by `memory_order_acquire`. With `memory_order_acquire`, *all* memory operations after the `acquire` -- dependent on the atomic variable or otherwise -- are forbidden from being reordered before it, whereas `memory_order_consume` only inhibits the reordering of *dependent* instructions. This is beneficial for more weakly-ordered architectures such as ARM and PowerPC which guarantee the ordering of data-dependent instructions without the need for an explicit barrier.

Since `memory_order_consume` deals with data dependencies, most use cases of it involve a `std::atomic<T*>`. Producer threads can build an entire data structure and publish the address of that data structure to the atomic pointer using `memory_order_release`. Consumer threads then load the atomic pointer with `memory_order_consume` and can establish a data dependency with the writer thread's stores if they use the pointer in a data-dependent manner, such as by dereferencing it. The standard guarantees that any dependent loads will reflect the writer thread's stores. Since the load of the atomic variable is done via `memory_order_consume` however, no guarantees can be made about the state of independent variables from the reader thread's perspective.

In your first example, none of the loads after `memory_order_acquire` can be reordered before it. However, in your second example, any reordering that doesn't have a dependency on `X` or the loaded value of it is fair game. Namely, `int dependent_x2 = *x_ptr_local;` (and the corresponding load from `dependent_x2` ) are guaranteed to remain ordered with respect to `X`, but that's it. All other reorderings are possible.

Comment: Thank you! Also you wrote about "data-dependent manner, such as by dereferencing it", i.e. `std::memory_order_consume` makes visible entire allocated area of memory pointed to by the pointer with consume-semantic, even if consume-pointer points to the middle of the array, then will be visible whole array? Will it work? `int arr[1000000]; std::atomic<int*> ptr;`  **thread-1:** `arr[0] = 255; arr[999999] = 127; ptr.store(arr+500000, std::memory_order_release);` **thread-2:** `int *p; while (!(p = ptr.load(std::memory_order_consume))); std::cout << *(p) << ", " << *(p + 499999);`

Comment: @Alex, I'll clarify my answer but because you are using the loaded value of `ptr` to calculate an offset into an array, it's essentially the same as using it as a dereference, and the data dependency holds. Notice, however, if you instead tried to `assert(arr[999999] == 127)`, this would _not_ be guaranteed to be true because you are not establishing a data dependency between the read-side `ptr` and the writes done on the producing side.

Comment: Do you mean that **thread-2:** `asser(p[999999] == 127)` will fail? But this is UB, because `p` in  **thread-2** shifted `+500000` with respect to the pointer `arr` from **thread-1** - and it is going beyond the boundaries. If you mean that **thread-2:** `asser(p[499999] == 127)` will fail, then why it can happen? In example for Release-Consume ordering, `void consumer() { std::string* p2;
    while (!(p2 = ptr.load(std::memory_order_consume))); assert(p2[4] == 'o');` it never will be false: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

Comment: @Alex, I did mean `arr[999999]` in **thread-2**, such that it is _not_ undefined behavior by exceeding the array bounds. It can fail because `arr` has no dependence on `p`. Thus, the load from `arr[999999]` can be reordered before the load from `p`. However, if you were to do in **thread-2**, `assert(p[499999] == 127)`, you are maintaining the dependence on `p`.

Comment: I agree. Thank you for the clarification.